# Выбор значений из ArrayList согласно ключу HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Помогите пожалуйста в следующей проблеме. У меня есть список `ArrayList`, и связанная с ним карта `HashMap`.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList phoneName = new ArrayList();
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 000");
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 100");
map.put("Егоров В.В.", phoneName);

phoneName.add("8 800 2000 200");
map.put("Андреев А.А.", phoneName);

phoneName.add("8 800 2000 300");
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 400");
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 500");
map.put("Михалёв Д.Д.", phoneName);
```

Мне нужно выбрать из `ArrayList` только те записи, которые соответствуют определённому ключу `HashMap`. Пробовал делать так, но это не работает.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(map.containsKey("Егоров В.В.")) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что у вас для всех ключей в мапе список будет один?

Comment: Всм я же присваиваю определенные значения из списка к ключам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно после добавления записи в `HashMap` создавать новый `ArrayList`. Используя один список, вы будете иметь по всем ключам в `HashMap` один и тот же `ArrayList` со всеми номерами.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> phoneName = new ArrayList<String>();
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 000");
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 100");
map.put("Егоров В.В.", phoneName);

phoneName = new ArrayList<String>();
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 200");
map.put("Андреев А.А.", phoneName);

phoneName = new ArrayList<String>();
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 300");
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 400");
phoneName.add("8 800 2000 500");
map.put("Михалёв Д.Д.", phoneName);
```

Получить по ключу значение из `HashMap` модно методом `get`.

```
String key = "Егоров В.В.";
System.out.println(map.get(key));  // [8 800 2000 000, 8 800 2000 100]
```

Пройтись по номерам в цикле можно так:

```
for(String value : map.get(key)){
    System.out.println(value);
}
```